# sorting dates to closest by a given time in swift

Tags: swift, date

I have a list of date strings in which I want to sort the list closest to the given time. If two times are clashing then earlier date priority would be considered.

```
var givenTIme = "10:00AM"

var strDates = ["2021-04-30 10:00AM", "2021-04-16 10:00AM", "2021-04-26 12:00AM", "2021-04-28 09:00AM"]

var output = ["2021-04-16 10:00AM", "2021-04-30 10:00AM",  "2021-04-28 09:00AM", "2021-04-26 12:00AM"]
```

in here we have to find sort the array dates close 10:00AM
If anybody knows the solution please help me out.

Comment: What have you tried? And why are you not working with Date objects instead of strings?

Comment: Why don't you still have `Date` instance and only `String`. As said in your previous questions, keeping the `String` is adding painful conversions each time to `Date`.

Comment: no problem you can assume it as array of date Objects

Comment: String is shown just for explanatory purposes, in actual i have array of date objects only, can you please help if its dateobjects?

Comment: And what's `givenTIme`? DateComponents?

Comment: Since we have to sort the date objects only by nearest to given time (irrespective of date), that's why given time is in string

Comment: Not tested but https://pastebin.com/VLZFYSfr might give you some ideas...

Comment: @Larme can you help me out with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you need but something like this could be a start?

The strategy is to transform the data into things that can be easily compared to give the sort order that we want.

Working with dates and times is always tricky because of calendars and locale issues.

```
var givenTIme = "10:00AM"
var calendar = Calendar.current

let strDates = ["2021-04-30 10:00AM", "2021-04-16 10:00AM", "2021-04-26 12:00AM", "2021-04-28 09:00AM"]

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "y-M-d hh:mma"// hh:mma"
let dates = strDates.compactMap(formatter.date(from:))

struct CompareHelper {
    let date: Date
    let deltaT: Int
}

let hhmmformatter = DateFormatter()
hhmmformatter.dateFormat = "hh:mma"
let target = hhmmformatter.date(from: givenTIme)!

let dts = dates.map { date -> CompareHelper in
    let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    
    let targetMinute = calendar.component(.minute, from: target)
    let targetHour = calendar.component(.hour, from: target)
    
    let deltaT = (targetMinute + targetHour * 60) - (minute + hour * 60)
    
    return CompareHelper(date: date, deltaT: deltaT)
}

let sorted = dts.sorted { (lhs: CompareHelper, rhs:CompareHelper) -> Bool in
    if lhs.deltaT == rhs.deltaT {
        return lhs.date < rhs.date
    }
    else {
        return lhs.deltaT < rhs.deltaT
    }
}
```